# Reading live game stats league of legends

Tags: c#

Is there a way to read live game stats such as current health, mana and etc? Something like what this guy did.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-UWVuvDyk6Q

Comment: A video on Youtube isn't actually scientific proof, but yes, it seems possible and probable. Do you have a specific question?

Comment: Yes, you can read memory with C#, which is what he said he was doing on the video.

Comment: I just want to get these live data and send it to an arduino through a serial port so that i can display them on an LCD display or even control some lighting in my PC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.
https://developer.riotgames.com

Here's a library that wraps the API:
https://github.com/XeeX/LeagueOfLegendsAPI